# regex not match correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have this regex `(\d{1,30}\/)+\d{0,30}` that need apply it to this body:

```
باسلام

احتراما جهت تست 1395/06/28 و         اعداد1/23/3/00000 و اعداد 1،2،3
```

[image]
it not match

but if i press enter it will match

[image]

```
باسلام

احتراما جهت تست 1395/06/28 و      
اعداد1/23/3/00000 و اعداد 1،2،3
```

why?

Comment: Where are you typing the text? Is it a regex matching website?

Comment: Is the Arabic text right-to-left? I suspect the website doesn't understand that when highlighting the matches. The regexp looks fine.

Comment: Perhaps this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes. Probably your problem is doing unicode regex matches using a regex engine that only understands ASCII

Comment: @Nehal J Want Yes it is http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine Do you see the same behaviour on regex101.com ?

Comment: @NehalJWani regex101.com has only one match for   1395/06/28

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine Share link to the saved regex on regex101.com

Comment: @NehalJWani  https://regex101.com/r/gV6cV4/1

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine You didn't specify /g . See this: https://regex101.com/r/gV6cV4/2

Comment: @NehalJWani it's ok with your link but not work on http://regexr.com/ and my webiste!

Comment: @EdHeal the regex works fine on regex101 in JS mode. OP needs to show his JS code.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - i concur - Perhaps he(?) is not saving it as unicode

Comment: Don't rely on how regexr.com highlighting works. Online testers have some issues with highlighting matches against Unicode characters. If you enclose your RegEx in capturing groups `((\d{1,30}\/)+\d{0,30})` you'll see correct values are matched and captured.